# what is the most sided sturdy regular n-polygon that can be made with lego?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, geometric-construction

Was puzzeling with this question:

What is the most sided regular n-polygon that can be made with lego?

- It has to be sturdy (the polygon should stay in shape when pushed around)
- made with the normal lego bricks (not bend or angled bricks )
- no use should be made from non- obvious lego limitations (like the angle that bricks make under tension, the minimal angle two bricks make because bouncing against nobs no one of them.
- mathematicly precise

For people who don't know lego:

What is the most sided regular n-polygon 
where :

- all lengths are natural or rational or decided by some construction
- all angles are right or decided by some construction

Comment: Question unclear. The only regular polygon where all angles are right is the square. What do you mean, "decided by some construction"? Moreover, a square isn't sturdy, as it can be squashed into a rhombus.

Comment: You can make an equilateral triangle.  I suppose you can also make a rigid regular hexagon out of six equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The square is the only one.

To make any other regular polygon that's rigid, the sides would have to be exactly integer length to line up with another peg of a base of legos, which is arrived at by going an integer number of pegs to the right (say) and an integer number of pegs up (say).  This is a Pythagorean triple with integer sides.

This means that $\sin \theta$ is rational, where $\theta$ is the exterior angle of the regular polygon.  But we know that the exterior angles of regular polygons are $\theta = 2 \pi / n$ where $n \geq 3$ is the number of sides.  We also know from Niven's Theorem that if $\sin ax = b$, where $a,b$ are rational, then $b = 0, \pm 1/2, \pm 1$.

The only case which gives rational $\sin \theta$ is $n=4$, which is a square.

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding your assumptions.  But you can definitely make an equilateral triangle out of Legos, which seems to contradict your conclusion.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "sturdy." I can make a *really* sturdy square. I can interlock entire layers of 2x4 rectangles. I could probably toss it down the hall without breaking it. But an equilateral triangle? I'd only be able to do the perimeter. Not nearly as sturdy. But if you want to go that route, you could likely go pretty high I suppose.  My point was that given a lego base, you can't put anything on there except a square.